# How does one prevent nested function calls?

Tags: php, nested

First question, please forgive me if I do something wrong or this is a duplicate, I couldn't find another question similar.

I'm writing a very basic translater function `i18n($string1)` that, when given `$string1`, queries an index. If the string matches something in the index, it returns the translation `$string2`. If `$string1` doesn't exist in the index, a new entry is created in the index that the user can later write a translated `$string2` into.

The issue I want to try and solve is that a sloppy developer (me) might accidentally make a call `i18n(i18n($string1))`. The way this resolves is that the inner call finds `$string1` in the index, returns `$string2`, then passes that to the function again which tries to find `$string2` in the index. This would fail because `$string2` is the translation and it would prompt the user to translate the translation... which isn't helpful.

I believe what I want is, in the case that the function is called nested within itself, it returns the string `$string1`. Thus, it doesn't matter how many times I call `i18n` within itself, it always translates the string `$string1`.

What is the best way to do this? I considered using a static or global `$isCalled` variable, or a singleton, but I've been told in the past that these solutions are almost certainly evil and there's probably something better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your case could it be a solution to search if the parameter string appears in the translated strings prior to search in the filter?

Comment: This seems to be a bad approach to translation overall. It means you need to run every single possible code path to gather all your translations, which may be somewhat infeasible and is not really a deterministic way of working. Have you looked into gettext or a similar system (even homegrown if you prefer) which is based on an extractor function, which parses your source code and extracts all instances of (in your case) `i18n()`? In this case it's trivial to detect nested functions and it's a much saner translation workflow too.

Comment: @deceze I hadn't heard of gettext before, I'll study that now. Thanks!

Comment: Seriously do. There's no need to reinvent the process of i18n yourself. 1) you'll discover over time all the details you're missing which you need to keep adding, 2) you'll find that *the process* is surprisingly more important than the technical implementation. The implementation needs to match a workflow best suited for the task, and gettext does. gettext may seem archaic and intimidating at first, but seriously get used to the `_()`-`xgettext`-Poedit-`msgmerge` workflow.

Comment: @deceze I'm always in favour of using an existing implementation over writing my own. They have always had more time to make mistakes than I have.

Comment: Also see http://pology.nedohodnik.net//doc/user/en_US/ch-poformat.html for an excellent introduction to the file format.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for all the information! It looks like this is exactly what I needed. However, I'll leave this question open to try and gather more general answers to the question, "How does one prevent nested function calls", since it may be helpful to others for alternative applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have been told right.

You could go by analyzing the debug_backtrace(), but that is really time and ressources consuming. Also it is an not needed overhead of the translation function.

If a developer calls the translation function with an already translated string it is the developers responsibility to fix that problem not the softwares.

A way to avoid this double calling is to use [PHP_CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.php) and define coding standars which would forbid such usage. It would be though tough to check for those things if both functions are not in the same line.

Comment: The issue with using PHP_CodeSniffer is that I rarely write the literal `i18n(i18n($string1))` but may, for example, write a method that automatically translates the string before processing it then accidentally pass it a translated string. If it can't be efficiently prevented, I would at least like to warn the developer somehow so they can fix their code.

Comment: You can prevent this from happening if you would write a proper documentation.
You should NEVER touch user input. I think you should also not alter strings and translate them. You could do, but only in some very special occasions, like logging. Then you would log the original message which is NOT given translated to the function and save it somewhere and output it later through the translate function. That would be, because for the translation you may need a database connection or so which could cause the original problem.
But that is just an example. By default: Do not touch the anything.

Comment: I will mark this answer as accepted, since it appears relevant to any case where a developer wants to prevent a function being passed to itself. Thanks.